# How to match up lists?

Tags: python, django

I am making a todo list. I have a list of checkboxes and text fields that correlated to each other. I am creating the todo list with jquery and it outputs the following:

```
<li name="todo_li" class="todo_items">
     <input class="incomplete" name="done_item" id="chk_box1" type="checkbox" checked>
     <div id="chk_div1">asdf</div>
     <input type="hidden" name="todo_text" id="todo_text1" value="asdf">
     <a class="remove" href="">x</a>
</li>
<li name="todo_li" class="todo_items">
     <input class="incomplete" name="done_item" id="chk_box2" type="checkbox">
     <div id="chk_div1">asdf</div>
     <input type="hidden" name="todo_text" id="todo_text2" value="asdf">
     <a class="remove" href="">x</a>
</li>
<li name="todo_li" class="todo_items">
     <input class="incomplete" name="done_item" id="chk_box3" type="checkbox" checked>
     <div id="chk_div1">qwer</div>
     <input type="hidden" name="todo_text" id="todo_text3" value="qwer">
     <a class="remove" href="">x</a>
</li>
```

In my view I am getting all the todo_text and done_items with the following:

```
todo_text = request.POST.getlist('todo_text')                                                                                       
print todo_text                                                                                                                     
done_item = request.POST.getlist('todo_item')                                                                                       
print todo_item
```

The output returns:

```
todo_text= [u'asdf', u'asdf', u'qewr']
done_item= [u'on', u'on']
```

If I create an item and check the box right away, say items 0 and 2 in the todo_text array, how can I get the done_items to match up?

I was trying to do something alone these lines:

```
   List3 = []                                                                                                                      
   print List3                                                                                                                     
   for i in range(len(todo_text)):                                                                                                 
       for j in range(len(todo_item)):                                                                                             
           if todo_text[i] == todo_item[j]:                                                                                        
              List3.append(1)                                                                                                     
           else:                                                                                                                   
              List3.append(0)                                                                                                     
   return List3
```

I am trying to populate this models che_box field and todo_text fields with the above info.

```
class TaskTodo(models.Model):                                                                                                               
    chk_box           = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='')                                                                                
    todo_text         = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="")                                                                   
    submitter         = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)                                                                      
    date_created      = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)                                                                                
    date_updated      = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
```

Any suggestions?

Here is the form I am using:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lz6Tq/

Comment: You know that using `Form` will handle all this for you, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form like that will give you POST data like...

```
done_item=on&todo_text=asdf&todo_text=asdf&done_item=on&todo_text=qwer
```

...which is going to be a pain to parse, because each checkbox has the same `name`.

If you add in a `value` attribute for each checkbox matching the `id`, then you'll get...

```
done_item=chk_box1&todo_text=asdf&todo_text=asdf&done_item=chk_box3&todo_text=qwer
```

...so `request.POST.getlist('done_item')` will return `[u'chk_box1', u'chk_box3']` instead, from which you can infer than boxes 1 and 3 are checked.

Comment: While this was not the exact answer it did help me getting into the right direction. Thanks for letting me bounce ideas off of you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question. If you want to check for each todo_text if it is in todo_item you can do something like

```
List3 = [1 if e in todo_item else 0 for e in todo_text]
```

Comment: Close! So far it that returns [0,0,0] no matter what. When saving the form I would like to be able to set the checkbox that relates to the todo_text field on initial save. It's easy once the form is already populated. I am stuck on when creating a new item. Here is the form I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz6Tq/